# Ball is moving at same velocity despite changing velocity variable in unity

Tags: c#, scripting, unity-game-engine

I am creating pong and everything is working fine, however, I wanted there to be power-ups where the ball velocity changes. I have a velocity variable but it seems to change nothing but the speed at which the ball starts, then the velocity stays flat. Here is an image of the ball panel.
[image]

and here is the code inside the ball script

```
    public float ballVelocity = 1000;

Rigidbody rb;
bool isPlay;
int randInt;
public Vector3 velocity; 
float elapsed = 0;
private bool onLeft;
public Vector3 startPos = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
void Awake()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    randInt = Random.Range(1,3);
    velocity = new Vector3 (ballVelocity, ballVelocity, 0);

}

void Update()
{

    if (rb.transform.position.x < GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("paddle").transform.position.x) {
        print ("game over");

    }
    if (rb.position.x < 0)
        onLeft = true;
    else
        onLeft = false;

    elapsed += Time.deltaTime;
    rb.drag = 0;
    print(onLeft);
    if (elapsed > 5) {

        //rb.velocity *= .5f;
        elapsed = 0;

    }


    rb.maxDepenetrationVelocity = ballVelocity;
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && isPlay == false)
    {
        transform.parent = null;
        isPlay = true;
        rb.isKinematic = false;

        if (randInt == 1)
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector3(ballVelocity, ballVelocity, 0));

        }
        if (randInt == 2)
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector3(-ballVelocity, -ballVelocity, 0));

        }
    }
}
```

}

No matter what I have tried, or what I have looked up, nothing seems to help. Please someone help me with this. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to change an object's speed is to grab it's current velocity with rb.velocity, normalize it with .normalized, and then set rb.velocity to that vector multiplied by the speed at which you want the ball to go at.

Here is an example code for doing this:

```
void ChangeSpeed(float speed)
{
    Vector3 dir = rb.velocity.normalized;
    rb.velocity = dir * speed;
}
```

If your system is lossless (100% bounce, no drag, so on) after doing this, the ball will stay at that speed until you change it again.